# Oracle: Trying to retrieve a value, but if multiple matches occur return 'multiple'

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to create a query in Oracle DB that only returns one value. However if the query returns more than one row, return the value 'multiple'. Sample data

```
ID   Name    Lname
1    Joe     Reed
2    John    Reed
3    Lucy    Grim
```

Here is what I am trying:

```
select case when count(*) over() > 1 then 'multiple'
            else Name
End Name 
from name where lname = 'Reed'
```

Right now if it the result has more than one match query returns 2 or more rows. What I want is it returns the name if only one result or the word 'multiple' if more than one.

I want the result to be with only one row returned:

```
Name
Multiple
```

if I search for 'Grim'

```
Name
Lucy
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: lazy way - add "distinct"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to DISTINCT as suggested by @oldProgrammer, you could do

```
select...
fetch first 1 row only
```